# Facebook Fan Pages Creation Tools - Page Modo - FaceItPages - Short Stack - Social Page Builder

Tags: facebook-page

There are numerous Facebook Fan Pages Creation Tools out there. PageModo, FaceItPages, ShortStack SocialPageBuilder, North Social, Lujure, SplashLabSocial, TabSite, Hubze, thruSocial.

We can't find the api they are using to do this and we want to do it for our website users.

Does anyone know what api they are using.

Answer (score 0):

They work by creating a Custom Tab on each Fan Page. This Custom tab is actually an additional Facebook App that pulls/displays content from their server.

The methods invoked are all part of the Graph API, you may be interested in looking at the various ways you can [handle the Page object](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#tabs).